# Recovering CW complex structure from a space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $K$ be a topological space which is a solid triangle.  How can we topologically distinguish the vertices, edges, and interior of the triangle?

One answer is to consider the local homology of points.  The points with nontrivial local homology in dimension 2 are the interior points.  After removing rid of those, we are left with the 1-skeleton, and we can repeat the process.  The points with nontrivial local homology in dimension 1 are the interior points of the edges, and after getting rid of those we are left with the vertices.

Is there a better way of doing this, and does this generalize to arbitrary CW complexes?

Edit:  Answered in comments.  I see, so a manifold can really only have one "boundary," and points within this boundary cannot be distinguished topologically.

Comment: You cannot repeat the process: once you removed the interior of the triangle, the resulting space is homogeneous and you cannot tell apart vertices from points in the interior of edges.

Comment: The problem is real: there is no way to recover the CW structure from tthe space. This is obvious once you realize a space have many dfferent CW-complex structures!

Comment: A CW-structure determines a filtration of a space, i.e. an increasing sequence of subspaces, namely the skeleta of the structure. We have advertised in a joint book "Nonabelian Algebraic Topology" (EMS, 2011) an approach looking first at homotopical defined algebraic invariants of  filtered spaces.